# Differentiate child class from the list of parent

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, parent-child

I need to differentiate the childs in the list of the parent.
I have a parent list

```
List<Parent> all = new List<Parent>();

Parent c1 = new Child1();
Parent c2 = new Child2();

all.add(c1);
all.add(c2);
```

is there any way to check if the items in the list are Child1 or Child2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the list and do something depending on item type you can do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if(item is Child1)
    {
        var child1 = (Child1)item;
        child1.DoSomething();
    }
    else if(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

if using c# 7 then you can do it better by creating a temporary variable directly in the if statement:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if(item is Child1 child1)
    {
        child1.DoSomething();
    }
    else if(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or you can use `as` operator like below:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    var child1 = item as Child1;
    if(item != null)
    {
        child1.DoSomething();
    }
    var chil2 = item as Child2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want to know if the items are all of a certain type or all of one of the 2 types.

To determine whether all items are `Child1` instances:

```
all.All(item => (item is Child1))
```

To determine whether all items are `Child1` or `Child2` instances:

```
all.All(item => (item is Child1) || (item is Child2))
```